# Parse String to TimeZone ICT in Calendar java

Tags: java, android, date, kotlin, calendar

I am trying to parse a String into a Calendar but right now I'm having problems at TimeZone:
My code:

```
public static Calendar convertStringToFullDates(String dateString) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(PATTENT_FULL_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.US);
    try {
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse(dateString));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        DebugLog.e(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return cal;
}
```

and String :

```
String str = "Fri May 11 00:00:00 ICT 2018";
```

and pattern:

```
private static final String PATTENT_FULL_DATE_FORMAT = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
```

I tried but it throws an exception like this:

> Unparseable date: "Fri May 11 00:00:00 ICT 2018"

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Your code runs fine on my Java 11.

Comment: Me too, but one problem is the same code, when I run in android studio it throws exception like above, i don't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String str = "Fri May 11 00:00:00 ICT 2018";
        final String PATTENT_FULL_DATE_FORMAT = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(PATTENT_FULL_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.US);
        Date date = sdf.parse(str);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

Note that `java.util` date-time classes are outdated and error-prone and so is their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`. I suggest you should stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

If you are doing it for your Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

**Using the modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Fri May 11 00:00:00 ICT 2018";
        final String PATTENT_FULL_DATE_FORMAT = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(PATTENT_FULL_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.US);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(str, dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // Print the date-time in a custom format
        System.out.println(zdt.format(dtf));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2018-05-11T00:00+07:00[Asia/Bangkok]
Fri May 11 00:00:00 ICT 2018
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.